# Image not display in Newsletters

Tags: aem

I am sending the newsletter to the target leads via *day CQ mail service* in CQ5, My newsletter template contains an image from DAM (via drap/drop). My Newsletter sent successfully to the audience but image not getting display. Below is the img src generate once i receive the newsletter.

```
<img title="logo" alt="logo" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/dBvtBcRC6SpELT7-2A_TARSjSJ3t7HDuxtIKWk-QoU7yCISyVeR1JledcIr6oleEkY2SxBZgJwGsjeDn8VQA653Omj_MQHScJgbZ-kKwiC6YHNsfeE2dS8tErqhQKvQIG8Y5MGk3MJhHdyzAydO5JZNxUxvAjNlCVTXjOpyoC2J-K-062Ec8aaT-UpkinvASKg=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:4502/content/campaigns/myApp/Newsletter/Monthly-Newsletter/_jcr_content/header.img.png/1427268772034.png" class="CToWUd">
```

Any Idea how to resolve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail does not directly link to the image , they use proxies. From the img src you have posted the image link is

```
http://localhost:4502/content/campaigns/myApp/Newsletter/Monthly-Newsletter....
```

Since google's server can't reach your local instance the image is not being displayed.

References :

https://filippo.io/how-the-new-gmail-image-proxy-works-and-what-does-this-mean-for-you/

https://support.google.com/a/answer/3299041?hl=en